# What is suitable pattern for two classes which have difference in one class variable only?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

In details. In this question i've used simple example. But in real life, there is huge logic in methods with difference in one state variable only. 
Example. I have two classes which have method with the same logic. Difference between these two classes is in class variable which used in method.

```
class A {
    private String str = "A";
    void method() {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}

class B {
    private String str = "B";
    void method() {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

I suppose using inheritance i can achieve the result.

```
abstract class Abs {
    void method() {
        System.out.print(getStr());
    }
    abstract String getStr();
}

class A extends Abs {
    String getStr() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B extends Abs {
    String getStr() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

Is it good solution? Or there are any others, or maybe design-patterns to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's just a difference in value, they should just be two instances of the same class. Either you're overthinking this, or this is a bad example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: why not to set this variable value when you create instance of the class?

Comment: In a case such as this you should only take an argumento to the method: classA { getstring(s) {return s;}}

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a difference in value, they should just be two instances of the same class.

I would just pass the "variable" data to the constructor and be done with it.

```
class A {
    private String str;

    public A(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Then when using it

```
A a = new A("a");
A b = new A("b");
a.method(); // prints "a"
b.method(); // prints "b"
```

Comment: It would be even better to create only one class with and argument to the method.

Comment: @desoares in this case it would be pointless, imho. It depends on the occasion. What I wrote is a more general solution. It works better if, e.g., `str` is used in more than one method.